# TSQL bringing columns to rows ,

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[Snapshot of my data and what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcCqH.gif)

My Data is something like this  (I have attached a picture to show data and what I want too)

```
LoanNb  FullNm  Rule1   Rule2   Rule3   Rule4   …   Rule40  
100 A   Fatal   null    null    Warning     null    
200 A   null    null    Fatal   null        null    
300 B   null    Warning null    null        null    
400 C   null    null    null    null        null
```

I want it like this

```
LoanNb  FullNm  Rule Name   Outcome                 
100 A   Rule1       Critical                    
100 A   Rule4       Warning                 
200 A   Rule3       Critical                    
300 B   Rule2       Warning
```

I searched in the forum, I think I need to do unpivot, I am trying this, but not working. I am new to SQL.

```
select * 
From Tablename

Unpivot
(RuleOutcome for Rulename in ('Rule1', 'Rule2', 'Rule3', 'Rule4')
) unpiv
```

Comment: If this is a sql server question you should change the tag,

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error message? If not what data are you seeing and why is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table(LoanNb int, FullNm varchar(1),Rule1 varchar(10),Rule2 varchar(10), Rule3 varchar(10),Rule4 varchar(10),rule5 varchar(10))
insert into @t values
(100, 'A', 'Fatal', null, null, 'Warning', null),
(200, 'A', null, null, 'Fatal', null, null),
(300, 'B', null, 'Warning',null, null, null),
(400, 'C', null, null ,null, null, null)

SELECT loannb, fullnm, rules
FROM 
   (SELECT fullnm,loannb, rule1,rule2,rule3,rule4
   FROM @t) p
UNPIVOT
   (rules FOR setofrules  IN (rule1,rule2,rule3,rule4)
)AS unpvt;
```

result
loannb      fullnm rules

---

```
    100 A      Fatal
    100 A      Warning
    200 A      Fatal
    300 B      Warning
```

(4 rows affected)

Comment: It's working like a charm, Thank you, Appreciate the quick response!

Comment: P.Salmon, would you add some text at the start of this answer to explain what your fix was? What did the OP's solution do wrong?